# Set selected value in asp.net DropDownList using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have ASP.Net DropDownList bind using c#.
I want to change selected value of DropDownList on Button Click Event using JQuery.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server" >
</asp:DropDownList>


           I have tried this but did not work:          
      $( '#< %=ddlSubject.ClientID %> option:selected' ).val( "5" );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't enclosed your dropdown in any grid or other container, use this:

```
$("#ddlSubject").val("5");
```

If not, use this:

```
$("#<%=ddlSubject.ClientID%>").val("5");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set value using this

```
$("#<%=ddlSubject.ClientID%>").val("5");
```

Comment: Try this ` $( '#< %=ddlSubject.ClientID %> option[value="5"]').attr('selected','selected').`

Comment: Badluck. Not working. I have bound dropdowlist using C# datasource. Is it because of that its not working?

Comment: You can set selected value from c# also.like this `ddlSubject.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = true;`

Comment: Yes I can. But I want to do it using jQuery/javascript only